# How to handle exception in external/unknown DynamicMethods assembly

Tags: c#, code-generation

I have a situation where I get an exception in a dynamic assembly, which in turn terminates my application. I assume this assembly is generated by some of the third party libraries we use, because we don't use `Reflection.Emit` or other codegen tools ourselves. However, as far as I can tell, there is no way for me to determine where it comes from?

This is the exception I get:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Unknown Module.
>
> Additional information: An item with the same key has already been added.

Is there tooling, or some code I can write into my own application, to figure out what is going on?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking. When the exception occurs you should have a stack trace that shows how the external code was invoked, at least. Do you want it broken down inside the generated code, and if so, how?

Comment: No, I do not get any stack trace, sorry if that was not clear. Nothing. Not even a module reference or name.

Comment: Can you post an example of the exact message you are getting?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: Just added. As you can see, it's not very helpful... Well, I can see that somewhere a Dictionary or Set is likely to be involved, but that is about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Debug -> Exceptions:

[Exceptions dialog http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/CommunityServer-Blogs-Components-WeblogFiles/00-00-00-82-17-metablogapi/5824.image_5F00_thumb.png](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/12/01/the-exceptions-dialog-vstipdebug0039.aspx)

then check the *Thrown* checkbox on the *Common Language Runtime Exceptions* line (or directly on the `ArgumentException` line). This will make the debugger kick in as soon as any exception is thrown, before the stack is unwinded. You'll be able to examine the call stack at this point.

Note that you *may* also have to disable the following option:
Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> Enable Just My Code

And in the call stack window, enable *Show External Code* from the context menu:

[call stack context menu http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/CommunityServer-Blogs-Components-WeblogFiles/00-00-00-82-17-metablogapi/5672.image_5F00_thumb_5F00_3.png](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/10/24/show-external-code-vstipdebug0031.aspx)

Comment: Thank you! The only question left in my mind is why this was reported as coming from an unknown module. When I now got to the exception, it is in very normal, non-emitted code...

Comment: @carlpett is it executed in a different thread? If you let an exception propagate out of a thread, [it will forcefully terminate your process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228965.aspx).

Comment: Probably, yes. The exception happened during clean-up, and it seems something still held a reference to the disposed object and called a method on it. 
Still, I don't get why the stack trace was gone?